# Decompile SenchaTouch app

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a SenchaTouch app in production compiled with SenchaTouch CMD tools. I was wondering if it is possible to decompile it to get a version closer to develop version (not minified etc). I belive it is SenchaTouch >2.0.

Comment: No, not possible. The information about the variable names isn't retained anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
sencha app build testing
```

is as close at it gets.

Alternatives:

- use intelliJ and press STRG-ALT-L